# Select drop down menu with input using Selenium

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping, selenium-chromedriver

I'm trying to select a year in the dropdown menu in this web page: https://servicio.indecopi.gob.pe/buscadorResoluciones/competencia_elim_barrer_buroc.seam
I was using Select, but it doesn't work:

```
Select(driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="FormListado1:cmd_vc_distcomboboxButton"]'))
```

It have the next error: `Select only works on <select> elements, not on <input>`. Do you know how I can select this input element?

Answer (score 0):

This is not a Select rather input element, so to open the drop down menu you can use this:

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//input[contains(@id,"PrimeraNormalcomboboxButton")]').click()
```

Now you can select any item from the opened menu like this:

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//span[@class="rich-combobox-item" and text()="2015"]').click()
```

Just use the correct year value.
Don't forget to add waits / delays.